# Cross-origin resource sharing for Tomcat 5.5

Tags: javascript, tomcat, http-headers, cross-domain, cors

I am new to Cross-origin resource sharing and I want to enable it in a Tomcat 5.5 server. Anybody can give me some hint how can this be achieved?

I want to set the header universally for all requests, and to allow all origins (`Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *`)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1653308/access-control-allow-origin-multiple-origin-domains

Comment: Sorry, but that does not answer to my question. It's fine for me to allow all domains (by using `*`), but what I need is to configure it for Tomcat.

Comment: Hi, I think the accepted answer is outdated, please consider switching to my answer below so that people have the chance to see there exists a standard mechanism in Tomcat now.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

If it's a static site, then starting with Tomcat 7.0.41, you can easily control CORS behavior via a [built-in filter](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/filter.html#CORS_Filter).

Pretty much the only thing you have to do is edit the global `web.xml` in `CATALINA_HOME/conf` and add the filter definition:

```
     <!-- ================== Built In Filter Definitions ===================== -->

      ...

     <filter>
       <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
       <filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter</filter-class>
     </filter>
     <filter-mapping>
       <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
       <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
     </filter-mapping>

    <!-- ==================== Built In Filter Mappings ====================== -->
```

Be aware, though, that Firefox does not like `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` and requests with credentials (cookies): [*when responding to a credentialed request,  server must specify a domain, and cannot use wild carding.*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Requests_with_credentials)

Comment: +1, I think this was a perfect answer to the question.

Comment: any way to have multiple domains without wildcard? firefox rejects commas in this header

Comment: I tried to follow this answer, but I had no clue where in the xml hierarchy I should add this definition. Can somebody please add this clue to the answer, for the people that are not so falimiar with the particular xml hierarchy in web.xml? thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Here is a Tomcat filter for adding CORS support: https://bitbucket.org/jsumners/corsfilter

Comment: I am not able to figure out how does it helps to solve the question.